# How to get varying shades of red colour based on an input value in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, hex, rgb

In python, how can I get varying shades of the red/yellow colour based on an input value between -1 and 1? If the value is between -1 and 0, the function should return yellow colour.
If the value is between 0 and 1, the function should return various levels or shades of the red colour. More specifically, if the value is 0, then the colour returned should be the standard red colour #FF0000, but if it is 1, then the returned value should be vanishing light red.

My code below shows colours that are not always red (or does not appear to be red).

```
import colorsys
import matplotlib.colors as mc

def get_red_shade(value):
    if value < -1 or value > 1:
        raise ValueError("Input value must be between -1 and 1")
    
    if value <= 0:
        # For values between -1 and 0, return yellow
        return '#ffff00'
    
    # Convert the input value to a hue value between 0 and 1
    hue = (1 - value) / 2
    
    # Convert the hue value to an RGB value
    r, g, b = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, 1, 1)
    
    # Convert the RGB value to a hex code
    return mc.to_hex((r, g, b))
```

I appreciate if the function returns hex code of the colour. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `hue = (1 - value) / 2`, it looks as though you are generating the whole range of hue values, but this is not what you want because the hue determines the color. I think you want to restrict the range so that the color gradually changes from yellow to red for positive values. You already have a proportion, so you can simply multiply by the range limit. For example, `hue = (1 - value) / 2 * 0.3` gives us:

[image: colors]